# Javascript Quiz Result based on Totalscore User

Tags: javascript, dynamic, output

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm stuck in a problem. I want that the quiz can display different types of texts afterwards, that reflects what the user has entered.
So if score/answerTotal is less than 5 it must say: "*you must try harder*".
If answerTotal is between 5 and 10 it must say: "*Good job*".
And if answerTotal is greater than 10 it must say: "*you are excellent*".

Can someone help me out how to fix this? My code is below. Thank you in advance!

```js
const questions = [
    {
      "question": "Wat is jouw IQ?",
      "answer1": "under 18",
      "answer1Total": "1",
      "answer2": "18 - 30",
      "answer2Total": "2",
      "answer3": "over 30",
      "answer3Total": "3"
    },
    {
      "question":
        "You make plans with a friend and they cancel on you, what do you do?",
      "answer1":
        "Say \"whatever\" and plan a night that'll be GREAT so they don't cancel again.",
      "answer1Total": "3",
      "answer2": "Feel hurt because you were looking forward to tonight.",
      "answer2Total": "2",
      "answer3": "No problem, you kinda wanted to stay home anyway.",
      "answer3Total": "1"
    },
    {
      "question": "Which of the following colours do you like most?",
      "answer1": "Black",
      "answer1Total": "1",
      "answer2": "Yellow or light blue",
      "answer2Total": "2",
      "answer3": "Red or orange",
      "answer3Total": "3"
    },
  ]

  let currentQuestion = 0;
  let score = [];
  let selectedAnswersData = [];
  let scoringData = [];
  const totalQuestions =questions.length;

  const container = document.querySelector('.quiz-container');
  const questionEl = document.querySelector('.question');
  const option1 = document.querySelector('.option1');
  const option2 = document.querySelector('.option2');
  const option3 = document.querySelector('.option3');
  const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next');
  const previousButton = document.querySelector('.previous');
  const restartButton = document.querySelector('.restart');
  const result = document.querySelector('.result');

  //Function to generate question 
  function generateQuestions (index) {
      //Select each question by passing it a particular index
      const question = questions[index];
      const option1Total = questions[index].answer1Total;
      const option2Total = questions[index].answer2Total;
      const option3Total = questions[index].answer3Total;
      //Populate html elements 
      questionEl.innerHTML = `${index + 1}. ${question.question}`
      option1.setAttribute('data-total', `${option1Total}`);
      option2.setAttribute('data-total', `${option2Total}`);
      option3.setAttribute('data-total', `${option3Total}`);
      option1.innerHTML = `${question.answer1}`
      option2.innerHTML = `${question.answer2}`
      option3.innerHTML = `${question.answer3}`
  }


  function loadNextQuestion () {
      const selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
      //Check if there is a radio input checked
      if(!selectedOption) {
          alert('Vul een antwoord in');
          return;
      }
      //Get value of selected radio
      const answerScore = Number(selectedOption.nextElementSibling.getAttribute('data-total'));

    
      ////Add the answer score to the score array
      score.push(answerScore);

      selectedAnswersData.push()


      const totalScore = score.reduce((total, currentNum) => total + currentNum);

      //Finally we incement the current question number ( to be used as the index for each array)
      currentQuestion++;

          //once finished clear checked
          selectedOption.checked = false;
      //If quiz is on the final question
      if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions - 1) {
          nextButton.textContent = 'UITSLAG';
      }
      //If the quiz is finished then we hide the questions container and show the results 
      if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
          container.style.display = 'none';
          result.innerHTML =
           `<h1 class="final-score">Your score: ${totalScore}</h1>
           <div class="summary">
              <h1>Summary</h1>
              <p>Possible - Personality Traits, see below for a summary based on your results:</p>
              <p>15 - 21- You Need Help</p>
              <p>10 - 15 - Good Soul</p>
              <p>5 - 10 - Meh </p>
              <p>5 - Are You Even Real</p>
          </div>
          <button class="restart">Opnieuw</button>
           `;
          return;
      }
      generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
  }

  //Function to load previous question
  function loadPreviousQuestion() {
      //Decrement quentions index
      currentQuestion--;
      //remove last array value;
      score.pop();
      //Generate the question
      generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
  }

  //Fuction to reset and restart the quiz;
  function restartQuiz(e) {
      if(e.target.matches('button')) {
      //reset array index and score
      currentQuestion = 0;
      score = [];
      //Reload quiz to the start
      location.reload();
      }

  }
  generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
  nextButton.addEventListener('click', loadNextQuestion);
  previousButton.addEventListener('click',loadPreviousQuestion);
  result.addEventListener('click',restartQuiz);

  function selectOnlyThis(id){
    var option = document.getElementsByName("option");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(option,function(el){
      el.checked = false;
    });
    id.checked = true;
  }
```

````css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
  background: no-repeat linear-gradient(250deg, #ff934f, #db222a);
}
.quiz-container {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  padding: 25px 40px 40px 40px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #00000010;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, gray, white);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.title {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 17px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-right: -17px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  margin-left: -17px;
}
.question {
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.option {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: black;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
}
.option:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.option input:checked .option {
  background: #08038c;
  color: #000;
}
.controls > * {
  margin: 30px 10px 0px 0px;
}
button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
button.previous {
  background: #F10849;
    border: 2px white solid;
}
button.next {
  background: #F10849;
  border: 2px white solid;
}
button.restart {
  background: #F10849;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
button.restart:hover {
  color: white;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  transform: scale(1);
  font-weight: 500;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.result {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.final-score {
  color: #00000099;
}
.summary {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #ffffff50;
  color: #00000099;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.summary h1 {
  align-self: left;
}


hr {
  border: 2px;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}


input[type="checkbox"] {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(check_radio_sheet.png) -38px top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}


</style>
```
````

```html
<head>
    <title>Personality Quiz</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="quiz-container">
        <div class="title">Test Personality</div><hr>
        <div id="question" class="question"></div>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
            <span class="option1"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="2" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
            <span class="option2"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="3" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
            <span class="option3"></span>
        </label>
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="previous">Vorige</button>>
            <button class="next">Volgende</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="result">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I thought to add something like this to my Javascript: 

if (answerScore = 0 && 5) {
      $link.text('You must try harder');
    } else if (answerScore = 5 && 9) {
      $link.text('Good job');
      }
    } else (answerScore => 10) {
      $link.text('You are excellent');
      }

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add below line in place when you want to display result and add text value into the  (but I'll propose to use here ) instead of 'Summary'.

```
const text = (totalScore < 5 && 'You must try harder') || (totalScore <= 10 && 'Good job') || 'You are excellent';
```

```js
const questions = [
    {
      "question": "Wat is jouw IQ?",
      "answer1": "under 18",
      "answer1Total": "1",
      "answer2": "18 - 30",
      "answer2Total": "2",
      "answer3": "over 30",
      "answer3Total": "3"
    },
    {
      "question":
        "You make plans with a friend and they cancel on you, what do you do?",
      "answer1":
        "Say \"whatever\" and plan a night that'll be GREAT so they don't cancel again.",
      "answer1Total": "3",
      "answer2": "Feel hurt because you were looking forward to tonight.",
      "answer2Total": "2",
      "answer3": "No problem, you kinda wanted to stay home anyway.",
      "answer3Total": "1"
    },
    {
      "question": "Which of the following colours do you like most?",
      "answer1": "Black",
      "answer1Total": "1",
      "answer2": "Yellow or light blue",
      "answer2Total": "2",
      "answer3": "Red or orange",
      "answer3Total": "3"
    },
  ]

  let currentQuestion = 0;
  let score = [];
  let selectedAnswersData = [];
  let scoringData = [];
  const totalQuestions =questions.length;

  const container = document.querySelector('.quiz-container');
  const questionEl = document.querySelector('.question');
  const option1 = document.querySelector('.option1');
  const option2 = document.querySelector('.option2');
  const option3 = document.querySelector('.option3');
  const nextButton = document.querySelector('.next');
  const previousButton = document.querySelector('.previous');
  const restartButton = document.querySelector('.restart');
  const result = document.querySelector('.result');

  //Function to generate question 
  function generateQuestions (index) {
      //Select each question by passing it a particular index
      const question = questions[index];
      const option1Total = questions[index].answer1Total;
      const option2Total = questions[index].answer2Total;
      const option3Total = questions[index].answer3Total;
      //Populate html elements 
      questionEl.innerHTML = `${index + 1}. ${question.question}`
      option1.setAttribute('data-total', `${option1Total}`);
      option2.setAttribute('data-total', `${option2Total}`);
      option3.setAttribute('data-total', `${option3Total}`);
      option1.innerHTML = `${question.answer1}`
      option2.innerHTML = `${question.answer2}`
      option3.innerHTML = `${question.answer3}`
  }


  function loadNextQuestion () {
      const selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
      //Check if there is a radio input checked
      if(!selectedOption) {
          alert('Vul een antwoord in');
          return;
      }
      //Get value of selected radio
      const answerScore = Number(selectedOption.nextElementSibling.getAttribute('data-total'));

    
      ////Add the answer score to the score array
      score.push(answerScore);

      selectedAnswersData.push()


      const totalScore = score.reduce((total, currentNum) => total + currentNum);

      //Finally we incement the current question number ( to be used as the index for each array)
      currentQuestion++;

          //once finished clear checked
          selectedOption.checked = false;
      //If quiz is on the final question
      if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions - 1) {
          nextButton.textContent = 'UITSLAG';
      }
      //If the quiz is finished then we hide the questions container and show the results 
      if(currentQuestion == totalQuestions) {
          container.style.display = 'none';
          const text = (totalScore < 5 && 'You must try harder') || (totalScore <= 10 && 'Good job') || 'You are excellent'; 
          result.innerHTML =
           `<h1 class="final-score">Your score: ${totalScore}</h1>
           <div class="summary">
              <h2>${text}</h2>
          </div>
          <button class="restart">Opnieuw</button>
           `;
          return;
      }
      generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
  }

  //Function to load previous question
  function loadPreviousQuestion() {
      //Decrement quentions index
      currentQuestion--;
      //remove last array value;
      score.pop();
      //Generate the question
      generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
  }

  //Fuction to reset and restart the quiz;
  function restartQuiz(e) {
      if(e.target.matches('button')) {
      //reset array index and score
      currentQuestion = 0;
      score = [];
      //Reload quiz to the start
      location.reload();
      }

  }
  generateQuestions(currentQuestion);
  nextButton.addEventListener('click', loadNextQuestion);
  previousButton.addEventListener('click',loadPreviousQuestion);
  result.addEventListener('click',restartQuiz);

  function selectOnlyThis(id){
    var option = document.getElementsByName("option");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(option,function(el){
      el.checked = false;
    });
    id.checked = true;
  }
```

````css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.7rem;
  background: no-repeat linear-gradient(250deg, #ff934f, #db222a);
}
.quiz-container {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px white;
  padding: 25px 40px 40px 40px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #00000010;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, gray, white);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.title {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 17px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-right: -17px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  margin-left: -17px;
}
.question {
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.option {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: black;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  font-size: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
}
.option:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
.option input:checked .option {
  background: #08038c;
  color: #000;
}
.controls > * {
  margin: 30px 10px 0px 0px;
}
button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
button.previous {
  background: #F10849;
    border: 2px white solid;
}
button.next {
  background: #F10849;
  border: 2px white solid;
}
button.restart {
  background: #F10849;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
button.restart:hover {
  color: white;
}
button:hover,
button:focus {
  transform: scale(1);
  font-weight: 500;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.result {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 2rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.final-score {
  color: #00000099;
}
.summary {
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #ffffff50;
  color: #00000099;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.summary h1 {
  align-self: left;
}


hr {
  border: 2px;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
}


input[type="checkbox"] {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(check_radio_sheet.png) -38px top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}


</style>
```
````

```html
<head>
    <title>Personality Quiz</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="quiz-container">
        <div class="title">Test Personality</div><hr>
        <div id="question" class="question"></div>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
            <span class="option1"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="2" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
            <span class="option2"></span>
        </label>
        <label class="option">
            <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="3" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this)"/>
            <span class="option3"></span>
        </label>
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <div class="controls">
            <button class="previous">Vorige</button>>
            <button class="next">Volgende</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="result">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, eRtuSa for your time and effort! I appreciate it. Now I can go on.